# Class Design in Laravel

Tags: laravel, class

Being new to app design and coding I have the following question related to Class design. I have a class by the name of Art Object which has the following other attributes:

- 'Type' such as 'Painting', 'Sculpture', 'Drawing', 'Collage' etc.
- Categories such as 'Modern (Art Nouveau)', 'Art Deco', 'Gothic' etc.

Now my question is, how do I design this. In my opinion I have two options:

1. Create a separate model , say ArtObjectTypes and have all the CRUD operations. And then establish relation between ArtObject and ArtObjectType.
2. Create a separate model , say CustomFields on which I can have all CRUD operations. The benefit in this case is that in future I will be able to generate more custom types attach with the ArtObject or any other Object.

Please advise which of the above options I should go for and why. Also, please do bring up if there is another choice.

Answer (score 2):

First ask yourself how you would organize this in your database.

Draw a schema like this:

[image: Database relation schema example]

Define the relations, the foreign keys, and only then you should start implementing the models. A model in laravel corresponds to a table in your database.